# When I wrote a robot API test for a GET request, I didn't get the expected response; instead, I got some HTML

Tags: python, api, pycharm, robotframework

Here is my code :

TC_001_Get request_fetech_trace status
[Tags]    API
[Documentation]    Tests the trace status.

```
Create Session      mysession    ${base_url}   disable_warnings=1
${Get_Response}     GET On Session     mysession    /api/v0/pam/traces/${newTraceUid}/traceStatus
Log To Console      ${Get_Response.status_code}
Log To Console      ${Get_Response.content}
Log To Console      ${Get_Response.headers}
```

My output like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLHzG.png)

how to solve this?

Comment: Solve what? You seem to issue a request and get an answer.

Comment: What is the response you are expecting?

Comment: The html you get looks like a login page - your call is most probably not authenticated while it must be, and an oauth2 system _(I'm guessing it's such)_ redirects the call to a login page.